# (VB.net) Find specified text on an entire line (not just beginning characters) in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, search, listbox

I have a listbox where each line contains a short 3-4 character model number followed by a tab and then the product name the model number corresponds to.  I also have a textbox which I am using to search the listbox.

The code I am using so far works somewhat, just not exactly how I would like.  If I enter search text it will highlight the results in the listbox but only for the first characters, is there anyway to search the text of an entire line (index) of a listbox?

Right now I am using the following:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged

    ListBox.SelectedIndex = ListBox.FindString(txtSearch.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried looping through every item in the listbox and doing listbox.items(i).contains = (txtsearch.text) and exiting the loop/setting selectedindex = i when there was a match but I am receiving inaccurate results.

Comment: What do you mean by "inaccurate"?

Comment: It will find items in the listbox that may meet the criteria of the search but not in a sequential order.  For instance, my listbox has its contents in alphabetical order and if I search for AC, it will select Cadillac instead of Acura.

Comment: Nevermind, it was an issue with upper/lower case.  I have it working now.

Comment: Rather than editing the title to indicate that the issue is solved, you can add the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by looping through and using contains.  Issues with upper and lower case were giving me incorrect results so I converted the criteria to all lower.

```
For i = 0 To ListBox.Items.Count - 1

     If ListBox.Items(i).ToString.ToLower.Contains(Trim(LCase(txtSearch.Text))) Then
          ListBox.SelectedIndex = i
          Exit For
     End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that your line representation is the ToString() of the item in the list:

```
ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text)
```

Comment: i tried this with no success.  thanks for your response though.

Comment: i managed to use part of this in my solution, thanks for your help.